# Getting all input into single box in dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have 5 dash inputs here that I want to get formatted into a single box in the app. There's a drop down box, calendar, and a couple other things. I'd like to organize these things into a single box/container in dash, since right now they're sort of scattered at the top of the app. This is the code I've used to get them into dash.

```
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Regression Analyzer for Individual Market Securities', style={'textAlign': 'center'
        }),
   
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id = 'my-date',
        min_date_allowed=date(2015, 1, 1),
        max_date_allowed=date(2020, 11, 11),
        initial_visible_month=date(2017, 8, 5),
        start_date=date(2015, 1, 1),
        end_date=date(2020, 11, 1)),
        
    dcc.Dropdown(id = 'MA',
    options=[
        {'label': 'Day Average', 'value': 'Day Average'},
        {'label': '7 Day Avg', 'value': '7 Day Avg'},
        {'label': '50 Day Avg', 'value': '50 Day Avg'},
        {'label': '200 Day Avg', 'value': '200 Day Avg'}
    ], value='Day Average'),
        
    dcc.Input(id = 'Name',
    placeholder='Enter stock ticker ...',
    type='text',
    value='AAPL'),
    
    html.Button('Submit', id='submit-val', n_clicks=0)

    ])
```

Comment: It looks like you already have them all in a single `div`, so I'm not quite sure what else you want to do. Can you explain more what the problem is?

Comment: Yea, but the layout is sloppy in the application. I'd like each item to be contained within a box but each time I try to mess around with the div I get an error.

Comment: like all the items in the div contained in a single box on the actual application page.

Comment: Do you want a border around everything? You can add a `style=dict(border='2 solid black')` prop to the containing div for that. If that is not what you want, are you able to share an image of what the page looks like now, and maybe a sketch of what you want it to look like?